# How to get gtest TYPED_TEST parameter type

Tags: c++, googletest

I have some unit tests written on Windows (Visual Studio 2017) and I need to port them on Linux (GCC 4.9.2 - I'm stuck with this version...). I've come with a simple example for my problem which compiles fine on Windows (I don't think it should compile as `MyParamType` is a dependent type from e template base class) and doesn't compile on Linux.

Example:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

template<typename T>
struct MyTest : public testing::Test
{
    using MyParamType = T;
};

using MyTypes = testing::Types<int, float>;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(MyTest, MyTypes);

TYPED_TEST(MyTest, MyTestName)
{
    MyParamType param;
}
```

> In member function ‘virtual void
>   MyTest_MyTestName_Test::TestBody()’:error: ‘MyParamType’ was not declared in this scope
>   MyParamType param;

By changing to:

```
TYPED_TEST(MyTest, MyTestName)
{
    typename MyTest<gtest_TypeParam_>::MyParamType param;
}
```

The code compiles, but it looks very ugly.

Is there an easy/nice way to get the template parameter type from a `TYPED_TEST`?

Comment: I've realized that gtest defines `TypeParam` exactly for this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is hidden in the docs:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

template<typename T>
struct MyTest : public testing::Test
{
    using MyParamType = T;
};

using MyTypes = testing::Types<int, float>;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(MyTest, MyTypes);

TYPED_TEST(MyTest, MyTestName)
{
    // To refer to typedefs in the fixture, add the 'typename TestFixture::'
    // prefix.  The 'typename' is required to satisfy the compiler.

    using MyParamType  = typename TestFixture::MyParamType;
}
```

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md

Comment: Is `TypeParam` the same thing? It seems to be defined to be `T`

Comment: Heads up, the link moved: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md

Comment: Note: this answer will lead to `-Wshadow` violations in newer GCC:
https://godbolt.org/z/9EPxbT7eW

Comment: @user1011113 Thanks for the heads up. This should probably be raised with the GoogleTest team. I must confess that I've been using DocTest for the past few years.

Comment: @RichardHodges I mean it's not really the fault of GoogleTest, this can be fixed easily by naming the `MyParamType` alias in the test something else. Not quite as neat but that's how C++ wants it...