# GTest - run multiple testcase on different parameters

Tags: c++, googletest

Note: I know this question was asked in different ways, but I couldn't solve it based on my restrictions:

1. I am using google test version `1.7`
2. Compiling in Visual studio 2010, with platform toolset V100

I am writing google test for a library I have created.

In my library, I have 3 structs, as follows:

```
struct utc_clock{ .... }
struct system_clock {....}
struct cpu_clock {....}
```

moreover, I have another class that uses them as **template** parameters.

In my test case, I do as follows:

```
TEST(MyTest, testImportantThings)
{
    time_point<utc_clock> tp = utc_clock::now();

    ASSERT_EQ(..things with tp... );
    ... more ASSERTION 
}
```

What I am trying to do, is to run

```
TEST(MyTest, testImportantThings)
```

multiple times for each of the `utc_clock`, `system_clock`, `cpu_clock`

I have looked into [How to get gtest TYPED_TEST parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234042/how-to-get-gtest-typed-test-parameter-type),

after that, I got the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyTest: public testing::Test{
    using MyParamType = T;
};

using MyTypes = testing::TYpes<utc_clock, system_clock, cpu_clock>;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(MyTest, MyTypes);

TYPED_TEST(MyTest, testImportantStuff)
{
    using clock = typename TestFixture::MyParamType;

    timepoint<clock> tp = clock::now();

    ASSERT_EQ(..things with tp... );
    ... more ASSERTION 

}
```

But I get the following errors:

1. > unexpected token(s) preceding ';' on: `using MyParamType = T;`
2. > testing::internal::TYpeList use of class template requires template
   >   arguement list online on: `using MyTypes = testing::TYpes<utc_clock, system_clock, cpu_clock>;`

and more...

Comment: Is it possible that your compiler is too old to support `using`?  What if you replace those with old-style `typedef` statements?

Comment: You are right. you can post this as answer if you want. this question can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your compiler is too old to support defining type aliases with `using`.  What if you replace those with old-style typedef statements?

For example, you could replace

```
using MyParamType = T;
```

With the equivalent:

```
typedef T MyParamType;
```